# Conditionally sum excel column based on other column

Tags: excel, sum, vlookup

I have 2 columns with following data

```
486 40
486 0
486 25
487 40
487 0
487 25
488 40
488 20
488 25
489 40
489 0
489 25
490 40
490 0
490 25
```

in another cell I want to add up values in the right i.e. for 490 the value should be (40+0+25).

Is there any formula I can use to do it across all other data.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"=490",B:B)
```

This formula examines the contents of the cells in column **A.**  If a cell has the value *490* then the value in column **B** for that row is included in the sum.

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: @LeaCohen .............I have tried to explain the formula..........if you can improve the elaboration, please feel free to edit my post.

Comment: Thanks, your explenation looks great.

Comment: Thanks Gary, THis does not help as I am not trying to add only if its 490, I have to add it for 488,487,486,485 and many more.

Comment: For more than one criteria I would use a **Pivot Table**